# Mysql query format issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql query to get data between 2 dates:

```
select * from `bookings` where `durationFrom`='$new_from_date' and  `durationTo` between '$new_from_date' and '$new_to_date'
```

How to write the above query in following way?

```
$this->db->select()
                 ->from('bookings')
                 ->where('durationTo',between $new_from_date and $new_to_date)
                 ->where('durationFrom',$new_from_date);
```

I'm using codeigniter...

This is my table:
[image]

I need to select data between given durationFrom and durationTo (durationFrom and durationTo entered by user)

eg:
If user select durationFrom=2016-02-25 and durationTo=2016-08-27, I need to get all the 5 rows

If user select durationFrom=2016-02-25 and durationTo=2016-05-27, I need to get first 3 rows

Comment: You need to tell which software you are using

Comment: Are you using codeigniter?

Comment: Which framework are you using? Laravel? Zend? Codeigniter?

Comment: Are you using a framework or procedural code? This will help us understand and be able to provide you with a answer.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter....Sorry to mention that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('bookings')
    ->where('durationFrom', $new_from_date)
    ->where("durationTo BETWEEN '".$new_from_date."' AND '".$new_to_date."'")
```

another option

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('bookings')
    ->where('durationFrom', $new_from_date)
    ->where('durationTo >= ', $new_from_date)
    ->where('durationTo <= ', $new_to_date)
```

you can replace the * in the select with the column name you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$where = "durationTo between "'.$new_from_date.'" AND "'.$new_to_date.'";
  $this->db->select('*')->from('bookings')->where('durationFrom',$new_from_date)->where($where);
```